# Remove author and date from doxygen generated html

Tags: doxygen

I have C++ code that is commented using doxygen style comments.
We use the template below.
Depending on the use of the documentation (internal vs external) we would like to remove the author and date in the generated html.
Is there an option to remove the author and date from the auto generated html?
Thanks!
Paul

```
/*!
*  \file Document.h
*  \brief This header file will be useful for the doxygen.
*
*  \author John.Doe
*  \bug    No known bugs.
*  \date   3/20/2016 
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

This will be difficult to achieve without some sort of modification to your header format.  The first and most obvious thing to try is using the `\cond` and `\endcond` conditional commands (or the `#ifndef DOXYGEN_SHOULD_SKIP_THIS` option) as discussed in the [Doxygen FAQ](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/faq.html).

Another trick you might consider would require you to reorder your `\bug` and `\date` commands so `\author` and `\date` are on adjacent lines.  If you did that, your header would look as follows:

```
/*!
 *  \file Document.h
 *  \brief This header file will be useful for the doxygen.
 *
 *  \author John.Doe
 *  \date   3/20/2016 
 *  \bug    No known bugs.
 */
```

By ordering things in this way, you could use a bit of alias trickery in your Doxygen configuration file to get the result you are looking for.  By changing the definitions for `\author` and `\bug`,  you can tell Doxygen to insert comment commands on the fly, ignoring the author and date information between them.  Using the lines below in your configuration file should cause the author/date entries to disappear from all HTML output.

```
ALIASES  =  author="<!--"
ALIASES  += bug="-->\bug"
```

This isn't exactly a design feature of Doxygen, but it's a hack that should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can use doxygen's `\internal` command - see http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdinternal

Essentially you'd need to slightly tweak your header example to put the elements that you want to exclude (author, date) after an \internal command:

```
/*!
*  \file Document.h
*  \brief This header file will be useful for the doxygen.
*
*  \bug    No known bugs.
*  \internal
*  \author John.Doe
*  \date   3/20/2016 
*/
```

Then in your Doxyfile you can enable/disable the `INTERNAL_DOCS` setting.

Slightly more advanced are the `\if` and `\cond` commands which will give you more fine-grained control over what appears, so you could have three or more different versions of the documentation for different user groups. See http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdif

Answer (score 0):

Remove the author and date entirely.

This information should not even be in `doxygen`, this is what source control management (i.e., `git`) is for.

Comment: `\author` is for more than blamelog-like purposes (which you're right, they should be tracked in SCM). It also serves purposes in copyright and licensing.

Answer (score 0):

For the newer versions of doxygen it is even easier when one has one line commands like in the example and all occurrences have to be removed. Since doxygen version 1.8.17 the command `\noop` exists (see https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html):

> \noop ( text to be ignored )
>
> All the text, including the command, till the end of the line is ignored. The command will most commonly be used in combination with ALIASES to ignore not supported commands that are present for e.g. other processing tools.

So it is sufficient to add the following lines to the doxygen configuration file:

```
ALIASES += author=\noop
ALIASES += date=\noop
```